# How do i find the last row index of each duplicates within the same column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a programme such that it can find the last row index of each duplicates that lie within the same column and store their values. For example in the picture, last row index of names with John,trump,alice and sarah should give me 13,17,23,26 respectively. Currently, my code can only identify the duplicates only so what can i do to find the last row index of each duplicate not only for the picture that i showed but also for all cases?

[image]

```
Sub Testing()

    Dim mycell As Range, RANG As Range

    With Sheets(1)

        ' Build a range (RANG) between cell F2 and the last cell in column F
        Set RANG = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    End With

    ' For each cell (mycell) in this range (RANG)
    For Each mycell In RANG

        ' If the count of mycell in RANG is greater than 1, then set the value of the cell 1 across to the right of mycell (i.e. column G) as "Duplicate Found"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RANG, mycell.Value) > 1 Then

        'how do i find the last row index of each duplicate here?

    Next mycell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be done a number of way. Used dictionary object in the code (tested) below. Please add Tool -> Reference -> Microsoft Scripting  Runtime.

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim mycell As Range, RANG As Range, Dict As Dictionary, Mname As String, Rng As Range
    Set Dict = New Dictionary
    With Sheets(1)
        ' Build a range (RANG) between cell F2 and the last cell in column F
        Set RANG = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With


    ' For each cell (mycell) in this range (RANG)
    For Each mycell In RANG
        Mname = mycell.Value
        ' If the count of mycell in RANG is greater than 1, then set the value of the cell 1 across to the right of mycell (i.e. column G) as "Duplicate Found"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RANG, mycell.Value) > 1 Then


        If Dict.Count > 0 And Dict.Exists(Mname) Then
        Dict(Mname) = mycell.Row()
        Else
        Dict.Add Mname, mycell.Row()
        End If

        End If
    Next mycell


    'Display result in debug window (Modify to your requirement)
    Startrow = 2
    For Each Key In Dict.Keys
    Set Rng = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Startrow & ":A" & Dict(Key))
    Startrow = Dict(Key) + 1
    ' Now may copy etc the range Rng
    Debug.Print Key, Dict(Key), Rng.Address
    Next



End Sub
```

Code modified to give a range object (as understood from comment)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how do i go about using the last row values stored in the dictionary for different names?

Comment: not clear about how you want to use the values? each key of the dict object is the name and 'Dict(Key)' gives the last row number.

Comment: Because i need to use the row index that is stored in dictionary to do something may be like copy the range that has the name trump, so i will need to do a loop based on the row index stored in dictonary like For i= lastrowjohn + 1 to lastrowTrump ... but in this case in the form of Dict which im not sure how to express it

Comment: sorry if it is out of topic, is it also possible to store the name of the duplicates that i found and put them into variables or even better into an array?  So that i can express them as array  something like Dim Arr: Arr = Array( "  ", "   ", "   ", "   ")  (not directly putting their names in the array as you can assume im not sure who are the names that are duplicated at the start..)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a DROPDOWN list with all names in b1 (by data validation)
2. In c1 paste the below function (to show the row number of where the last value appears)

```
{=MAX(($A$1:$A$26=$B$1)*ROW($A$A:$A$226))}
```